# How can I add two or more images using matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I read the images using imread and then I would like to compute the average image. How can I add(and divide) using matplotlib?

I'm searching for something like imadd in matlab.

Code:

```
img1 = matplotlib.image.imread("path")
img2 = matplotlib.image.imread("path1")
img3 = matplotlib.image.imread("path2")
```

Thanks

Comment: please show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: @cel I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal sum operations:

```
img4 = img1 + img2 + img3
```

This, however, is not exactly the same as [imadd](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadd.html) from matlab. Matplotlib works with RGB values from 0 to 1. As so the sum in some pixels will provide values superior to 1 (which for the array type is valid; the same would not be true if the data type were uint8). As so perform the following operation to guarantee that your data comes out correct:

```
img1 = matplotlib.image.imread("path1")
img2 = matplotlib.image.imread("path2")
img3 = np.clip(img1 + img2, 0, 1)
```

Notice that all images must have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

`matplotlib.image` is probably what you are looking for. You'll also need `numpy` if you want to manipulate the images otherwise, because they are basically just arrays in the size of the image (e.g. 1920 x 1080) with 3 or 4 dimensions (RGB or RGBA).

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = mpimg.imread("foo.png")
img2 = mpimg.imread("bar.png")
```

Now you are setup for image manipulation. In the case that your images are both in the same format and size (e.g. RGB. Check by using `img1.shape` and `img2.shape`) you can do:

```
img3 = plt.imshow((img1 + img2) / 2)
```